# Nested form not appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using cocoon gem for nested forms. My rails version is 4.2.6.

The association set between two models is as follows

**Question.rb**

```
class Question
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  has_many :choice_options, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :choice_options, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :topic, presence: true
end
```

**ChoiceOption.rb**

```
class ChoiceOption
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  belongs_to :question
end
```

And I have `new` and `question_params` set as follows in questions controller

**questions_controller.rb**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

      def new
        @question = Question.new
      end

        private

      def question_params
        params.require(:question).permit(:title, choice_options_attributes: [:id, :title, :_destroy])
      end
end
```

The partial form to create a new question and nested choice is as follows.

**views/questions/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/errors', object: @question %>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_area :title, rows: 3, required: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Options</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= f.fields_for :choice_options do |options_form| %>
        <%= render 'choice_option_fields', f: options_form %>
      <% end %>

      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add option', f, :choice_options %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit 'Create', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg' %>
<% end %>
```

And then I have created a partial form for choices which I am rendering in the above page.

**views/questions/_choice_option_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
  </div>
  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove option", f %>
</div>
```

Now when I am trying to click the **add option** link from the partial form, its not appearing. the url is ending at

```
 http://localhost:3000/questions/new#
```

Comment: What do you see when you 'inspect' the link_to_add_association with developer tools? Does the link include something like `<a data-association="choice_option" data-associations="choice_options" data-association-insertion-template="_CHOICE_OPTIONS_FIELDS CODE HERE"?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initiate the choice options in new

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @question = Question.new
    @question.choice_options.build
  end
end
```

Comment: Just tried this but still same issue. `add option` not giving a new form. And if I click create just with one question and one option its not creating.